# XString breakpoint thrown when defining string

Tags: c++, c++17

Hello i've had this break point being thrown by xstring for the last two days and I can't seem to get rid of it. First off the class i'm working with or at least the relevant bit.

```cpp
class myProjects {
public:
    std::wstring wstr;
    const wchar_t* BrowserPtr = wstr.c_str();
    std::string browser = "undeffined";
};
```

with that out of the way here is whats generating the error

```
void myProjects::setBrowser(std::string &str) {
    std::string cpy = str;
    browser = str; // this is the problimatic line
    wchar_t temp[21];
    size_t outSize;
    mbstowcs_s(&outSize, temp, sizeof temp, str.c_str(), str.size());
    wstr.assign(temp);
}
```

at least that's my goal the string definition alone still throws the error.
so here's the error.

```
Exception thrown: read access violation. this was 0x14.
```

and the surrounding code snippet

```
    basic_string& assign(_In_reads_(_Count) const _Elem* const _Ptr, _CRT_GUARDOVERFLOW const size_type _Count) {
        // assign [_Ptr, _Ptr + _Count)
        if (_Count <= _Mypair._Myval2._Myres) {  //here
            _Elem* const _Old_ptr   = _Mypair._Myval2._Myptr();
            _Mypair._Myval2._Mysize = _Count;
            _Traits::move(_Old_ptr, _Ptr, _Count);
            _Traits::assign(_Old_ptr[_Count], _Elem());
            return *this;
        }
```

Now I've tried a lot to get rid of this and I know that if I watch the variable browser in the debugger it says its information is unreadable and calling things like get capacity throw errors on read access as well. I do use strings else where in the program and even change wstrings and string back and forth but this is a new error. I also tried making browser private and a getBrowser function that was this.

People seemed to think by unreadable I meant garbage so I attached a screenshot of the dubugger.[image]

```cpp
std::string myProjects::getBrowser() {
    //std::string s(wstr.begin(), wstr.end());
    std::string newStr = "";
    return newStr;
}
```

with or without commented out line it throws same error. Further more putting the copy and pasted code snippet that generate the error into the error alone don't in a new project. Im just looking for some insight as to why this , might be happening. I am not using pointers in either function and the 0x14 is weird but if I try to reserve space same error. Frankly i'm just really confused and don't know what to do. I realize i didn't give something to throw in a compiler and i'm sorry but I really have no idea where the error would be dirrvided from or what types of things cause this error all i could find online was null pointers.
sorry for typos.

Comment: Btw; an identifier that starts with underscore and is followed by an uppercase letter (like `_Elem`) is *reserved for the implementation* and you are *not* allowed to use such identifiers in your own code.  There are many other reserved names (like double underscore *anywhere*, and more), but you are not currently tripping over any of those.

Comment: I changed nothing just thought the context might be useful. Honestly I'm just really confused.

Comment: `const wchar_t* BrowserPtr = wstr.c_str();` -- This looks awfully strange in a class declaration.  What is your intent here?

Comment: I know that was a massive pain but ```ShellExecute``` wanted a const wchar_t*. If theres a way to get around that and use normal string that would be great even if it doesn't fix the issue it would be awesome.

Comment: You shouldn't be using any `c_str()` until at the moment one is called for.  In other words, your entire application should use `std::wstring`, and only supply the functions asking for a `const wchar_t*` the `c_str()`.

Comment: If you use VS(I presume you do) use a debugger, I think your ws is corrupted meaning it contains garbage value, you should be able to see that in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible problem can be found in `class myProjects`:

```
class myProjects {
public:
    std::wstring wstr;
    const wchar_t* BrowserPtr = wstr.c_str();
    std::string browser;
};
```

When a variable of type `myProjects` is constructed, first `wstr` is constructed with an empty string, then `BrowserPtr` is initialized with a pointer to the data portion of the then empty string `wstr`.

However, as soon as you assign anything to `wstr`, it is quite likely that it frees the internal data buffer, and allocates a new one to hold the new string. This means that `BrowserPtr` is now pointing to a piece of memory that has been freed.

As PaulMcKenzie already mentions, don't store `BrowserPtr` this way, omit it from the class. Instead, the moment you need to pass a C string to another function, call `wstr.c_str()`.

Another issue is with the multibyte conversion:

```
wchar_t temp[500];
size_t outSize;
mbstowcs_s(&outSize, temp, size_t(256), str.c_str(), str.size());
```

First, why have an array of length 500 but pass 256 to `mbstowcs_s()`? It is better to ensure the values match:

```
mbstowcs_s(&outSize, temp, sizeof temp / sizeof *temp, str.c_str(), str.size());
```

Also note that if the input string is as large or larger than the length you pass to `mbstowcs_s()`, then there will be no null wide character written to the output. Either you have to check the result to ensure the result is *shorter* than the size of the output buffer, or you have to ensure you always add a null wide character at the end of the output buffer:

```
temp[(sizeof temp / sizeof *temp) - 1] = L'\0';
```

Of course, it's even better to first call `mbcstowcs(nullptr, str.c_str(), 0)` to get the required length of the output buffer. Then it is possible in C++17 to resize `wstr` to the right length, and pass `wstr.data()` to `mbcstowcs()` as the output buffer.

Comment: Thank you that defiantly helped my wstring mess that I was using. Somehow The the break is still being thrown. I'm sure this will prevent many future issues though. I also realized I had a 20 character limit on the string so I just put all that to 21 to account for the terminating char.